# Ruby On Rails -- Uploading image(paperclip) using custom views and controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, view, paperclip

So I tried uploading a paperclip image using:

views:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "basic_methods", :action => "update_image"}, method: :put) do%>
  <%= file_field_tag :banner_image%>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
  def update_image
    current_user.banner_image = File.new(params[:banner_image],"r")
    current_user.save
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

but I get this error:

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Comment: Doesn't Ruby give you line numbers for errors? Assuming it is the File constructor, have you tried debugging what is being passed to it? Have you read the File API docs to make sure you can create a new non-absolute File?

Comment: can you show us your model for which you are saving the paperclip image